# Ejemplo de consulta en MySQL trayendo la fecha pero con un formato en específico

Tags: mysql

En una tabla ‘X’ estoy guardando una fecha como la siguiente:

```
2018-05-02 16:30:53`
```

y es de tipo `DATETIME`, pero me gustaría tener un ejemplo de cómo hacerle para extraer la fecha de la tabla pero quitándole el `-` y los `:` y que me quede de la siguiente manera:

```
20180502-163053
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Intentaste algo al respecto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solo necesitas formatear la fecha con la siguiente funcion de mysql

```
DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d%m%Y-%H%i%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en php lo puedes hacer así:

```
$timepo = 2018-05-02 16:30:53;
$tiempo = explode("-", $timepo);//quitamos los guiones
$tiempo = explode(":", $tiempo); //quitamos los dobles puntos
```

Quedaría algo así 20180502 163053